# cross browser custom checkbox

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I have `HTML` and `CSS` code that I've used to build a custom checkbox. I believe my code has the correct web-kits but it doesn't seem to work on FireFox.

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
 <input type='checkbox' style="float: left" class='regular-checkbox big-checkbox'
     checked='checked' id='product-45-45' name='product_id_page-0[45-45]'
     value='45-45' data-first_price="11.99" data-second_price="" data-paysys="" />
```

**CSS**

```
.regular-checkbox {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border: 1px solid #cacece;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0),inset 0 -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0),inset 0 -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0),inset 0 -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    padding: 9px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.regular-checkbox:active,
.regular-checkbox:checked:active {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0),inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0),inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0),inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
.regular-checkbox:checked {
    background-color: #e9ecee;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0),inset 0 -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0),inset 15px 10px -12px rgba(255,0,0,0);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0),inset 0 -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0),inset 15px 10px -12px rgba(255,0,0,0);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0),inset 0 -15px 10px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0),inset 15px 10px -12px rgba(255,0,0,0);
}
.regular-checkbox:checked:after {
    content: '\2714';
    font-size: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 3px;
    color: #19a73e;
}
.big-checkbox {
    padding: 18px;
}
.big-checkbox:checked:after {
    font-size: 37px;
    top: -7px;
    left: 2px;
}
```

Screen shot of the desired outcome (works in Chrome):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try use this code, I don't know explain, but I did one version for you ;)

```css
.regular-checkbox{
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 38px;
  height: 38px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
 }
 .regular-checkbox input{
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
 }
 .regular-checkbox small{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
 }
 .regular-checkbox input:checked ~ small:after{
  content: '\2714';
  height: 38px; 
  width: 38px;
  color: green;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
 }
```

```html
<label class="regular-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <small></small>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you, +1 for answer

Comment: this one is slightly misaligned on MacOS chrome v76.0.3809.132 https://imgur.com/H5G39U9

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in Firefox - there's a workaround with using `<label>` and `<span>`.

MDN also mentions that styling some form elements is a bit of a pain - [read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Advanced_styling_for_HTML_forms#Check_boxes_and_radio_buttons).

```css
.checkbox input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}
.checkbox span {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  border: 1px solid #cacece;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), inset 0 -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  padding: 22px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.checkbox :active + span,
.checkbox :checked:active span {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.checkbox :checked + span {
  background-color: #e9ecee;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), inset 0 -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), inset 15px 10px -12px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
.checkbox :checked + span:after {
  content: '\2714';
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #19a73e;
  text-align: center;
}
.big-checkbox {
  padding: 18px;
}
.big-checkbox:checked + span:after {
  font-size: 37px;
}
```

```html
<label class="checkbox" for="product-45-45">
  <input type='checkbox' style="float: left" class='regular-checkbox big-checkbox' checked='checked' id='product-45-45' name='product_id_page-0[45-45]' value='45-45' data-first_price="11.99" data-second_price="" data-paysys="" />
  <span></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, +1 for explentaion